# React Native & iOS : Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native

I have been doing a project with react native. We were working in a team. The code was fine. Then one day my partner pushed an update to the repo. The code works fine in his macbook. But as for me, I got some errors as below. This error keeps on repeating in my console like an infinity loop. Please help me.

```
2021-04-27 16:50:58.651850+0900 MyApp[1722:470282] [native] Running application MyApp ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2021-04-27 16:50:58.716771+0900 MyApp[1722:470464] 7.6.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2021-04-27 16:50:59.389717+0900 MyApp[1722:470471] [native] RCTBridge required dispatch_sync to load RCTDevLoadingView. This may lead to deadlocks
2021-04-27 16:51:02.004739+0900 MyApp[1722:470468] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C6:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2021-04-27 16:51:02.006678+0900 MyApp[1722:470464] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C6] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-04-27 16:51:02.006797+0900 MyApp[1722:470464] TCP Conn 0x28068cb00 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2021-04-27 16:51:03.026929+0900 MyApp[1722:470488] [javascript] 'Locales =>', [ { isRTL: false,
    languageCode: 'en',
    languageTag: 'en-KR',
    countryCode: 'KR' },
  { isRTL: false,
    languageCode: 'ko',
    languageTag: 'ko-KR',
    countryCode: 'KR' },
  { isRTL: false,
    languageCode: 'ms',
    languageTag: 'ms-KR',
    countryCode: 'KR' } ]
2021-04-27 16:51:03.357908+0900 MyApp[1722:470488] [javascript] Initialize - Push, Notification
2021-04-27 16:51:03.402203+0900 MyApp[1722:470488] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTLog is not a registered callable module (calling logIfNoNativeHook)
2021-04-27 16:51:03.428189+0900 MyApp[1722:470488] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication) Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.021025+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.028693+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.031414+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.039040+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.044973+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.050134+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.054998+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 4923 and callID 2461 for module <unknown>. Args: '[231]'
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.060805+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 4939 and callID 2469 for module <unknown>. Args: '[232]'
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.065863+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 4955 and callID 2477 for module <unknown>. Args: '[233]'
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.070933+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.076179+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.081011+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 4971 and callID 2485 for module <unknown>. Args: '[234]'
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.086752+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 4987 and callID 2493 for module <unknown>. Args: '[235]'
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.092208+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.096989+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.102638+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.107905+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.113361+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.118681+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.124229+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.129071+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.134937+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.140182+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 5003 and callID 2501 for module <unknown>. Args: '[236]'
    2021-04-27 16:25:29.145136+0900 MyApp[1694:462504] [javascript] Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 5019 and callID 2509 for module <unknown>. Args: '[237]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're not focusing on the right error. With a quick lookup on *"Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module"*, I found a lot of help online, like this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26687#issuecomment-537504575

Thus, that's probably a common case, where you probably need to clean your cache, or / and you forgot to link a new library / install your pods.

Typical commands are:

```sh
$ watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset-cache
$ cd ios && pod install && cd ..
  OR
$ cd ios && rm -rf Pods && pod cache clean --all && pod install && cd ..
```

Then clean your project and build again under Xcode.